# C# Windows connecting to arbitrary VPN

Tags: c#, windows, vpn

If we have defined a VPN in the network settings of a computer, it is a relatively simple process to connect to it using rasphone/rasdial - however what if we want to connect to an arbitrary VPN?

Say I have the IP address, user name, password, and SSL settings available to my program. How would I go about creating such a connection programatically?